# Responsive images, per image type?

Tags: php, images, hooks, responsive

I am new to understand responsive images. Unfortunately the resources out in the internet did not help me to fully understand the concept, so please bare with me.

I would like to know hdavidow if it is possible to select and set the sizes for **full width, wide width, center- left- right aligned images** separately?

Is it possible to select and set the sizes for **post thumbnail, medium, large images** separately?

I would like to learn how to select **left- right- aligned large sized images** and and set the sizes with wp_calculate_image_sizes for them.

Edit: My use case for this is that I want to limit left- and right-aligned images to a maximum width of 45% using CSS. Additionally, I have centered images that  utilize the entire width of the post content. However, I am unable to formulate the rigth rules set.

I would like to target images on this CSS path "wp-block-image alignleft size-large", crate a rule for it. Then crate different rule for imgaes on this path. "wp-block-image aligncenter size-large".

As seen in this screenshot the left aligned image has 648px i would like to use the Medium Large (768px) that is automatically created by WordPress instead.

[image]

This is my test page. https://staging.earthstoriez.com/responsive-images.

Thank you, Kocj.